# New version of Microsoft Edge (83.0.478.56), cannot override user agent styles

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

On my website, I have CSS styles that prevent a border on inputs or textareas.  This works in Firefox, Chrome and until recently, Microsoft Edge.  With the latest update of Edge, focussed inputs and textareas have a border, which comes from "user agent styles".  Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/da6meyhb

```
<div>
   <textarea class="style1" rows="10">Hello World!</textarea>
</div>

textarea.style1,
textarea.style1:focus,
textarea.style1:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  resize: none;
}
```

This example has a textarea, with CSS styles to prevent a border.  In the new version of Microsoft edge (83.0.478.56), the textarea, when focussed, still has a black border.

How can I disable this border?

Comment: Same issue in Chrome, they changed something recently regarding default formatting for focused form fields, and the new Edge uses the Chromium rendering engine. Using dev tools in a current Chrome, it is easy enough to figure out that this is not indeed a border, but an outline …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CBroe said, there have the same issue in the Chrome browser, then focus on the textarea, it also displays the black border in the textarea.

To disable the border, try to add `outline: none !important;`, [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/ka0fgzo9/) as below:

```
<style>
    textarea.style1,
    textarea.style1:focus,
    textarea.style1:hover {
        background-color: aqua;
        border-style: none;
        border-width: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        resize: none;
        outline: none !important;
    } 
</style>
```

The output in Edge browser (Version 83.0.478.56 (Official build) (64-bit)) like this:

[image]